# Scrapy extracting <li> with span inside

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests, scrapy-shell

I'm trying to extract the text from this html structure:

```
<div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
    <span class="font-weight-bold">List of Birds</span>
        <ul class="bird-forms">
            <li>Crow <span class="color">Black</span></li>
            <li>Peacock <span class="color">Multicolored</span></li>
            <li>Dove <span class="color">Multicolored</span></li>
            <li>Sparrow <span class="color">Brown</span></li>
            <li>Goose <span class="color">Multicolored</span></li>
            <li>Ostrich <span class="color">Multicolored</span></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Using scrapy shell: `response.css('ul.bird-forms li ::text').extract()`

**I want to the result to look like this:**

```
['Crow Black', 
 'Peacock Multicolored',
 'Dove Multicolored', 
 'Sparrow Brown', 
 'Goose Multicolored',
 'Ostrich Multicolored']
```

**Instead of this:**

```
['Crow',
 'Black', 
 'Peacock',
 'Multicolored', 
 'Dove', 
 'Multicolored', 
 'Sparrow', 
 'Brown',
 'Goose', 
 'Multicolored',
 'Ostrich', 
 'Multicolored']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use XPath `string()`:

```
birds = []
for li in response.xpath('//ul[@class="bird-forms"]/li'):
    bird = li.xpath('string(.)').get()
    birds.append(bird)
```

Comment: This is the best approach! The only issue is that the output list are mixed with 'Single quote ' and "Double  quote", I even try to run replace on ``bird = li.xpath('string(.)').get().replace('""', "''") ``  but didn't change nothing. Other than that it's perfect.

Comment: Hmm... I don't understand where did you get quotes. Could you show your output?

Comment: It's not that important I just got a  list looks like this: ``['Crow  Black',
 "Peacock  Multicolored",
 'Dove  Multicolored',
 'Sparrow  Brown',
 "Goose  Multicolored",
 'Ostrich  Multicolored']``.  some element with single quote and some with double quote but it was working fine python does complain about it. That was the best approach!

Answer (score 1):

You need to separately select `li` tags first and additionaly select text for each `li` tag:

```
data = []
for li_tag in response.css("ul.bird-forms li"):
    data.append(" ".join(li_tag.css("*::text").extract()))
```

the same as python list comprehension:

```
data = [" ".join(x.css("*::text").extract()) for x in response.css("ul.bird-forms li")]

print(data)
# output <class 'list'>: ['Crow  Black', 'Peacock  Multicolored',
# 'Dove  Multicolored', 'Sparrow  Brown', 'Goose  Multicolored', 'Ostrich  Multicolored']
```

Answer (score 0):

We can pull the details separately and merge them after :

```
   li_tags = response.xpath(".//ul[@class='bird-forms']//li/text()").extract()
    color_tags = response.xpath(".//ul[@class='bird-forms']//span[@class='color']/text()").extract()


[" ".join(entry) for entry in zip(li_tags, color_tags)]

['Crow  Black',
 'Peacock  Multicolored',
 'Dove  Multicolored',
 'Sparrow  Brown',
 'Goose  Multicolored',
 'Ostrich  Multicolored']
```

Comment: I am already getting the same result as yours, what I want is:  ```['Crow Black', 
'Peacock Multicolored'...],``` instead of  ```['Crow ',
 'Black',...]```

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. My bad